# Count the SSRS Dataset rows after applying the filter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

So I have a dataset in SSRS called "CRMDecisions". I am counting the number of rows for this Dataset using the following expression in a text-box outside of the tablix:

```
=CountRows("CRMDecisions")
```

Now, this dataset also has a number of duplicate records and i want to toggle between the unique counts and everything including the duplicate counts. I have used the below filter to hide the duplicate rows I don't want to see:

```
=IIF(Fields!Company.Value = Previous(Fields!Company.Value) AND 
Fields!DaysAway.Value = Previous(Fields!DaysAway.Value) AND 
Parameters!ShowPortfolio.Value = "False", True, False)
```

Right now, I get a count of all the rows no matter what filter view I am using. How can I get the count of the dataset after removing the duplicate rows?

Comment: Have you just hidden the rows in the table/matrix or have you filtered them in the dataset properties?

Comment: You can use SUM(IIF(Fields!Company.Value = Previous(Fields!Company.Value),1,0)

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have hidden them in the "Row Visibility" >> "Show or hide based on an expression", where the first two conditions are being used to remove duplicates and the third one is based on boolean parameter

Comment: @TonyDong this gives me an error: The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox180.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses a Previous function in an outer aggregate.  Previous functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates.

Comment: @himanshumalik Could you add extra column to has this number 1 or 0 so you can sum it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For counting all the rows you can use (like you already did):

```
=CountRows("CRMDecisions")
```

For counting all the unique rows (without duplicate) you can use the following expression (note that you need put the field into the expression which holds the duplicates):

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!CompanyWithDuplicates.Value)
```

If you want some special counts you can always use this expression:

```
=Sum(IIF(       'Your True condition'      , 1, 0))
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Company.Value = "MyCompany", 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you @Strawberryshrub ..this worked for me. Is it possible to do this for a couple of columns together? For example Column A has Company and column B has decision type. If a Company has two records with different decision types (Say Company Apple has Decision type PP as well as EE), then I would want to count both these entries in the total expression),.. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you mean somethink like that? `=Sum(IIF(Fields!CompanyDecisionType.Value = "PP" or Fields!CompanyDecisionType.Value = "EE", 1, 0))`